# Should I add Pods to VCS?

Tags: git, version-control, cocoapods, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using CocoaPods to integrate open-source libraries to my app and VSC, saying BitBucket to keep track my project.

Scenario: I use a computer (at work) to add new libraries to `Podfiles`, and then use another work station (at home) to pull data from the remote repository, it will require me to do `pod update` for the new libraries added using `Podfiles`, which is ok.

Point is as long as I do pod update in the home computer, it will generate files asking me to add my repo. Should I also keep track those files?

My expression may not be very clear, so I take [SwiftPhotoGallery](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftPhotoGallery) as an example. I use SourceTree as my Git client.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether you should be versioning library files used by your Swift program, then the answer is most likely no.  Instead, you should just allow CocoaPods to manage libraries anywhere you want to develop your project.  There are many reasons not to version your Swift library files.  One reason already hinted is that CocoaPods will probably do a much better job than you in keeping library files up to date.  Another reason is that in general one should avoid versioning binary files with Git because it does not handle binaries well.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying in the 2nd computer I should unstage or remove those files? Is using .gitignore a good idea in this case?

Comment: This is entirely another question if you have already done this.  If you really  versioned library files it could be tricky to get rid of them.  Ideally your libraries should be someone _outside_ of your .Git folder.

Comment: As I use CocoaPods, all of the 3rd-party libraries are in Pods folder. Isn't unversioning them easy by just commenting out all the libraries in Podfiles, push the app with removed Pod libraries up to Git, and then uncomment the libraries? Do you want me to file a new question for this?

Comment: No...even if you `git -rm` the libraries, they will still be in the history

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Even I do so, those files are still in my remote repo. Not sure how to get rid of them. So should I use .gitignore next time or just simply unstage the files/libraries I don't want to keep track of? Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: Look into using `filter-branch` if you really want to remove all traces of the library files.  If the libraries are stored _inside_ your .git folder then yes `.gitignore` might be an option.  If the libraries are stored _outside_ your .git folder then you don't need to do anything; they cannot be versioned by accident.